# Reading a 5-D double data structure in matlab

Tags: matlab

How do I read a 5-D data structure (of type double) in matlab? I have loaded the data in matlab and it says 5-D double. How do I read it afterwards

Comment: Add more information, this question is too broad…

Comment: Do not use the word structure in the context of numeric arrays. You ha a **5D double array**. You can access the content with the usual indexing, i.e. `data(:,:,1,1,1)` to 'access' the matrix on the first layer, for the first box (4th dimension), for the first stack (5th dimension). Note that I named the 4-5th dimension arbitrarily to heklp intuition.

Answer (score 2):

With the current information I cannot say much, but usually this is a good first try:

In matlab navigate to the file, right click on it and choose import data.

The import wizard is quite powerful so you have a good chance to get the data you need from that. Afterwards you may need to try `help reshape` if it does not have the right dimensions yet.